# Nothing shows up when using the Google Analytics Embed API

Tags: javascript, api, google-analytics

I am trying to use the google analytics embed api to embed analytics data to my website. I tried implementing the demo examples, using my own client ID, but nothing shows up. The divs on my website just defaults to display:none. I copied all the code from the examples, what could i be doing wrong?

I used this example:
https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/

Comment: Can you share your code with us? There might be an implementation issue that is preventing you from succeeding.

Comment: Check also the error in the console of the browser.

Comment: Hi, i'm using the exact code from this example: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/basic-dashboard/